How to determine watersheds on quadrics for a given up vector?
Given a quadric (either defined by matrix, vector, constant $Q$, $P$, $R$ or by 10 constants $A, ..., J$) and an up vector $u$, how can one find the watershed line(s) for the quadric?
A watershed, intuitively, is a line that divides the surface into sub-surfaces based on where a raindrop (falling in inverted up direction) would flow. If two raindrops falling on two sides of a line end up in the same point, the line is not a watershed. Raindrops are thought to only flow on surfaces whose normal has an angle < 90° with the up vector.
I think in the presence of ridges, it is equivalent to those sections of a ridge (line of locally maximal curvature) where the normal's angle with the up vector is < 90°.
However, there are quadrics that don't have ridges, but do have watersheds, e.g. a lying cylinder (where the set of all highest points forms a watershed).
Please note that e.g. for a sphere, there is no well-defined watershed (or rather, the entire up-facing surface is the watershed). If at all possible, I'd like to have an arbitrarily defined line for these cases.
Another definition: Take any plane that contains the up vector and intersect it with the quadric. Determine the maximum wrt to the up vector. The union of all maxima of all such planes are the quadric's watersheds.
I think that e.g. on an ellipsoid, the watersheds will branch infinitely towards the edge. The focus should be on getting the longest branches.

What is a watershed?

I edited the question.
